# Element like Literal in Ext.NET

Tags: ext.net, string-literals

Is there an element like asp:literal in Ext.NET to push string elements inside the tag? I am trying to implement a treeview and I get some data in JS. I want to pass this string into ext:TreePanel tag by an element like literal. Is there any tag using in ext.net like this?

Answer (score 0):

The `<ext:Label>` might be your best best. You can set the `.Html` property.

**Example**

```
<ext:Label runat="server" Html="<h2>Hello World</h2>" />
```

Hope this helps.